# Simplest way to sum two Lists in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have two lists, I want to sum each element in list A with the element in list B, producing a new list.

I can do it with:

```
List(1,2).zip(List(5,5)).map(t => t._1 + t._2)
```

Is there any simpler or neater way to do this in Scala?

In Clojure I can just do:

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

Comment: Lisp-y `map`s typically work with functions that take any number of inputs. Scala, Haskell, and friends, on the other hand, only define `map` for functions that take 1 input. So in Scala, you will always need to perform some form of zipping to cram multiple inputs into a single tuple.

Comment: Lisp seems nice in some ways.

Comment: Also note `map` in lisp is similar to what I am used to calling `zipWith`, `zipWith3`, etc in Haskell.

Comment: Yes, and `zipWith`/`zipWith3` in Haskell is what we call `.zipped.map` in Scala.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For two lists:

```
(List(1,2), List(5,5)).zipped.map(_ + _)
```

For three lists:

```
(List(1,2), List(5,5), List(9, 4)).zipped.map(_ + _ + _)
```

For n lists:

```
List(List(1, 2), List(5, 5), List(9, 4), List(6, 3)).transpose.map(_.sum)
```

Comment: What if the values in list are in option

Answer (score 10):

missingfaktor's answer is what I would have recommended, too.

But you could even improve your snippet to get rid of using the clumsy _1, _2:

```
List(1,2) zip List(5,5) map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to simplify:

```
import Function.tupled
List(1,2).zip(List(5,5)) map tupled {_ + _}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scalaz:

```
List(1,2) merge List(5,5)
```

Works also for lists with different sizes: `List(1,2,3) merge List(5,5)` will return `List(6,7,3)`